# External module without import statement in Typescript

Tags: typescript, module

The moment you add an `import` statement to your Typescript file, this file is considered an external module. So this is not a problem:

**File.1.ts**

```
import { Type } from '...';
let whatever = 123;
...
```

**File.2.ts**

```
import { Type } from '...';
let whatever = 234;
...
```

So this works. But the moment one removes those two `import` statements, these files aren't considered modules any more and both variables with the same name become global interfering with each other.

### Question

How does one *force* modularization of a source file that doesn't have any import statements?

Comment: You could `export` something?

Comment: From [official Quick start guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html): In TypeScript, just as in ECMAScript 2015, any file containing a top-level `import` or `export` is considered a module.

Comment: @Paleo: Not having anything to import or export. It's defining angular routing using static inline config objects.

Comment: @lenny: That's true, but I'm not asking when it's considered a module, but rather how can make it as module if I don't have anything to import or export? Define a module? A namespace?

Comment: there is no other way than exporting your variable: `export const whatever = 234;`

Comment: I think the commenters (both here and in answers below) are talking in circles.  You are asking how to make TypeScript consider this a little-m `module`, as in force it to interpret the file in "module mode", but the point is that your code is by definition not a big-M Module, in the CS 101 (201?) sense of the word, because code that does not import or export anything is by definition not modular. A black box with no openings -- no input or output -- cannot by definition do useful work (in a modular, vice global context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required to `import` or `export` something. I suggest to export an `undefined` value:

```
export let undefined;
```

The compiler generates no code for this instruction.

Comment: how about a simple `import '';`?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I think an import of an nonexistent module is not valid. Even if the compiler doesn't complain, it creates a variable for the import. It's not clean.

Answer (score 2):

As of TypeScript 4.7, this is solved via `"moduleDetection": "force"` in your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ... Various options here, such as module ...
    "moduleDetection": "force"
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleDetection

Original Github issue which drove this config: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14279

Answer (score 0):

Beware it's quite **hacky** but ...

#### given:

*it's NOT a module,

doesn't export anything

nor exports nothing,

and can't be modified

you can't include it in the project, or tsc will complain about duplicates*

so ... you can't set it's state
or ..pass parameters
and... you cant't read it's output/results

then ...you want it because of it's side effects?

```
// file: notamoduleA.ts:
let x = "x";
(global as any).x = x;

// file: notamoduleB.ts:
let x = "y";
(global as any).x = x;
```

make it a module?

```
// file: index.ts:

import * as ts from "typescript";
import * as fs from "fs";

eval(
    ts.transpileModule(
        fs.readFileSync(
            "./external/notamoduleA.ts", "utf8")+
             "\n export = {name: 'A'}",{
                 // options ...
             }             
    ).outputText
);

console.log((global as any).x);

eval(
    ts.transpileModule(
        fs.readFileSync(
            "./external/notamoduleB.ts", "utf8")+
             "\n export = {name: 'B'}",{
                 // options ...
             }             
    ).outputText
);

console.log((global as any).x);
```

or in the browser, bundle that kind of code
and at runtime  create a script element and load it ?

Comment: I didn't say it's not a module. All my files are modules because they do import and/or export stuff. This one should be a module FWIW it's just that it doesn't import and/or export anything so TSC doesn't see it as such.

Comment: Yeah, I got that ...but... **"it's just that it doesn't import and/or export anything "** , so ... its not a module :),  
In any case I think the best options is to do it the ts way and, as Paleo suggested, import/export something

Comment: I've found out I can also do a simple `import '';` which doesn't throw an exception and also doesn't import anything. But satisfies the import requirement.